# How to avoid TLB miss (and high Global Memory Replay Overhead) in CUDA GPUs?

Tags: caching, cuda, gpu, hpc, tlb

The title might be more specific than my actual problem is, although I believe answering this question would solve a more general problem, which is: how to decrease the effect of [high latency (~700 cycle)](http://www.sisoftware.net/?d=qa&f=gpu_mem_latency) that comes from random (but coalesced) global memory access in GPUs.

In general if one accesses the global memory with coalesced load (eg. I read 128 consecutive bytes), but with very large distance (256KB-64MB) between coalesced accesses, one gets a high TLB (Translation Lookaside Buffer) miss rate. This high TLB miss rate is due to the limited number (~512) and size (~4KB) of the memory pages used in the TLB lookup table.

I suppose the high TLB miss rate because of the fact that virtual memory is used by NVIDIA, the fact that I get high (98%) Global Memory Replay Overhead and low throughput (45GB/s, with a K20c) in the profiler and the fact that partition camping is not an issue since Fermi.

Is it possible to avoid high TLB miss rate somehow? Would 3D texture cache help if I'm accessing a (X x Y x Z) cube coalesced along X dimension and with a X*Y "stride" along the Z dimension?

Any comment on this topic is appreciated.

Constraints: 1) global data can not be reordered/transposed; 2) kernel is communication bound.

Answer (score 4):

You can only avoid TLB misses by changing your memory access pattern. A different layout of your data in memory can help with this.
A 3D texture will not improve your situation, as it trades improved spatial locality in two additional dimensions against reduced spatial locality in the third dimension. Thus you would unnecessarily read data of neighbors along the Y axis.

What you can do however is mitigate the impact of the resulting latency on throughput. In order to hide *t* = 700 cycles of latency at a global memory bandwidth of *b* = 250GB/s, you need to have memory transactions for *b* / *t*  =  175 KB of data in flight at any time (or 12.5 KB for each of the 14 SMX). With a fully loaded memory interface and a high ratio of TLB misses, you will however find that latency gets closer to 2000 cycles, requiring roughly 32 KB of transactions in flight per sm.

As each word of a memory read transaction in flight requires one register where the value will be stored once it arrives, hiding memory latency has to be balances against register pressure. Keeping 32 KB of data in flight requires 8192 registers, or 12.5% of the total registers available on an SMX.

(Note that for above rough estimates I have neglected the difference between [KiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte) and [KB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte)).

Comment: Thank you tera for the explanation! Unfortunately, this is what I was expecting.